# What is the best way to get started with iOS development using Xamarin/C#?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I've done a lot of searching and haven't really been able to stumble across anything extremely useful in really getting myself going with iOS development using Xamarin/C#.

For those who were once newbies like myself,  is there a recommended tutorial or online classes that anyone can recommend to really get me going?  Something that starts from a hello world type app up to a completed and somewhat useful app?  I've found nothing but hello world tutorials so these haven't been too useful.

I am proficient in C#/Visual studio and Windows software development and have been doing it quite some time now and I am trying to make the leap into mobile development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [guides on Xamarin.com](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides) are amazing it's a good place to start but if you want a more complete starting lesson i suggest you to take a look at [this course on tutplus.](http://code.tutsplus.com/courses/building-ios-apps-in-c-with-xamarin)
It's not free but if you sign-up, for one month you can check the course for free which is enough time for this course

Comment: The tutplus one looks exactly like what I need to get a jumpstart.  A good visual too (since they are videos).  I will take a look at Xamarin.com as well.  Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

search for [Jesse Liberty](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=jesse%20liberty%20xamarin) on the web

Comment: This looks good and I like how it is taking place as we speak.  I need something right now though but I will definitely be referring back to this since he covers App unit testing as well which is perfect because I work full-time as an automated tester for a company and this will come in handy. Thank you!